# Cross Compiling of C source file to Android Arm

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I'm trying to make a cross compiler on C language in mobile devices from windows using nim . I have managed until compilation but I cannot export/push it on my phone using USB debugging
 below is the batch file I've created.. can anyone tell me what's wrong? I just want to compile directly to my mobile device using gcc or clang.

```
@echo off

set PATH=%PATH%;C:/Users/PCTechRinz/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows/bin

 nim c --cpu:arm --os:android --compileOnly hello.nim

path = C:/cygwin/bin

g++ -I../sysroot/usr/include -I/path=D:/Installer/nim-0.19.0/lib -pie -o hello.bin hello.cpp stdlib_system.cpp

path = C:/Users/PCTechRinz/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
 adb root
 adb push hello.bin /data/local/tmp/hello.bin
 adb shell 

cd /data/local/tmp/hello.bin
chmod 755 hello
./hello
pause
```

below is the what I am getting

```
Hint: used config file 'D:\Installer\nim-0.19.0\config\nim.cfg' [Conf]
Hint: system [Processing]
Hint: hello [Processing]
Hint: operation successful (12267 lines compiled; 0.268 sec total; 10.773MiB pea
kmem; Debug Build) [SuccessX]
adb: error: failed to get feature set: no devices/emulators found
error: no devices/emulators found
The system cannot find the path specified.
'chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I have enabled USB debugging on my phone

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an Android toolchain to build for Android. Your system's g++ targets Windows, not Android.

I'd strongly suggest using ndk-build or CMake, but if you need to use Clang directly for some reason you should use a [standalone toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain).